# error = 24 when application run for 10 mins in ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, crash, uiimage

I have created an application which consists of a screen with a play button to play an audio file. The problem occurs after running the application for 10 minutes; it throws this message in the console:

> ImageIO: CGImageRead_mapData 'open'
>   failed
>   '/Users/indianic/Library/Application
>   Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/4.2/Applications/A511E515-6FEA-4D0D-A5C5-95740B14C858/VisualMath.app/pi_play.png'
>   error = 24 (Too many open files)

After these message the application crashes. Anyone knows why this problem occurs and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to know what's causing an error message that states "Too many open files"? At a guess, you're opening files somewhere and not closing them. However, without seeing some code, it's impossible to know what you're attempting to do/what could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

As I have work with database in the same application there is some point where i need to fire sql query twice. because I have fire query twice the database file is not  getting close and because of that the file open many time in my application. and because of that the application is crash with giving this error.

so always check for the database file is getting close or not for this kind of the error.

Comment: i have same problem face in my project due to this error i get "nib could not be load" and my view also change in to iphone one if i run in ipad.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem.  For me it had to do with the number of iterations (count) rather than time running, and I just tracked the problem down to my use of the stop method.  It appears that the stop method leaves some resources in memory that release does not (I'm guessing for a possible resume).  And even if you call release after stop, which is what I was doing in audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully: , it's wasn't enough if i'd used stop beforehand.  But replacing stop with just release and nothing else made my problem go away.

Comment: Hi John ,
 My problem is also with number of iteration not time . as you said I have also stop my video player and then release so non of the resource can be in memory . My question is any thing else that i need to do with I have try many thing but still the same problem 
Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Sorry, I have no other insights.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you keep loading images for the play button which causes the exception. If this is the case, try loading them once and change the icon of the button when needed.
If you are using NSFileHandle close the file when you are done with it, or use [UIImage imageNamed:(NSString *)];

Comment: Hi Sami,

I am not keep loading the images for the button. But I have make button in XIB and load from the XIB.

Comment: So how do you load pi_play.png? from XIB as well?

Comment: Yes, I have set uibutton in xib type is custom and set image.