# Crash when change view (not always)

Tags: iphone, xcode, crash, nib

I have a problem, and it is the first time that I have gotten this error. I have a navigation based app with a database. The app reads the database and displays the content. Sometimes, when I go back in the `navigationcontroller` I get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle /Users/kikko/Library/ApplicationSupport/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/2A14BA37-78AB-47A9-B92B-5166D6C76B50/FlagsQuiz.app (loaded)' with name 'Bandiera''

First throw call stack:

> (0x15a1022 0x1732cd6 0x1549a48 0x15499b9 0x303638 0x1a91fc 0x1a9779 0x1a999b 0x1a8fec 0x1cff1d 0x1ba1cb 0x1d0df1 0x1d0ea9 0x3ca508 0x187401 0x18808b 0x3c9d6c 0x1b0857 0x1b09bc 0x1b09fc 0x7f19 0x15a2e99 0xe514e 0xe50e6 0x18bade 0x18bfa7 0x18b266 0x10a3c0 0x10a5e6 0xf0dc4 0xe4634 0x148bef5 0x1575195 0x14d9ff2 0x14d88da 0x14d7d84 0x14d7c9b 0x148a7d8 0x148a88a 0xe2626 0x2182 0x20f5 0x1)
>   terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your NIB or in the class Bandiera. Check twice this files in your target.
Here is related question [NSInternalInconsistencyException Could not load nib in bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415252/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-could-not-load-nib-in-bundle)

Comment: I've just check it but seems to be all ok, is so strange because if I wait some second before go back all work, while in some situation if I go back faster I get this crash