# NSInternalInconsistency Exception

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am tearing my hair out over this Exception. Someone please help me with this. I can send the symbolicated Device logs.This happens when i click on my action button for recording a video.

```
- (IBAction)recordAndPlay:(id)sender {
[self startCameraControllerFromViewController:self usingDelegate:self];
```

The Exception i get is.

```
2013-07-04 10:28:56.243 InstagramVideoEditor[7525:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[PLCameraView _displaySizeForPreviewForCameraMode:], /SourceCache/PhotoLibraryServices/MobileSlideShow-1928.4/Sources/PLCameraView.m:953

2013-07-04 10:28:56.251 InstagramVideoEditor[7525:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: ''

*** First throw call stack:
(0x30c59b6f 0x3ac9e6af 0x30c59a49 0x3161102b 0x36f3043d 0x36f30629 0x36f30c15 0x36ede93d 0x36ee003b 0x36f3d091 0x36f0ccc3 0x33266821 0x332b3165 0x332b3133 0x332b26e1 0x332b2541 0x332b2335 0x3328640d 0x3324dce3 0x32eedc9f 0x32eed85f 0x32eee799 0x32eee15f 0x32eedf6f 0x32eedde5 0x30c2253d 0x30c1ff19 0x30c205b1 0x30b970cf 0x30b96ebb 0x35679793 0x33293a59 0xa27b5 0x3b1c4ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415252/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-could-not-load-nib-in-bundle

Comment: I have tried all the solutions posted but no luck for me so far!

Comment: Here are the logs https://github.com/muhammadwarisali/logs

Comment: From the logs I wonder if 'self' is being released when the library goes to use it as the delegate.  What is the reference count of self shortly after this method is called?