# What does internalconsistency mean?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/C8CF9D6E-4B29-416B-8973-A6F18C0CE691/.app> (loaded)' with name 'BGCinemaScheduleCell''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x32d812a3 0x3aa2697f 0x32d811c5 0x34d26571 0x34d2e2b7 0x137e4d 0x13833f 0x1383fd 0x1b6b97 0x34dffdef 0x17218b 0x34bd454d 0x34bb9313 0x34bd07cf 0x34b8c803 0x34936d8b 0x34936929 0x3493785d 0x34937243 0x34937051 0x34936eb1 0x32d566cd 0x32d549c1 0x32d54d17 0x32cc7ebd 0x32cc7d49 0x3688b2eb 0x34bdd301 0xa1385 0x3ae5db20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Okay there is indeed an actual XIB named BGCinemaScheduleCell

I got this error here:

```
-(void) vLoadMainBundle
{
    if ([self class] == [BGBaseTableViewCell class])
    {
        return;
    }

    NSString * className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:className owner:self options:nil];
}
```

I have no idea what NSInternalInconsistencyException mean. the value of className is loadNibNamed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5646337/2027232

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the xib hasn't been copied to the bundle resources that an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5646337/2027232 would work.

The next question would be why the xib isn't copied to the bundle resources when I created it.

Comment: Sometimes XCode decides to un tick the 'target' box when adding new classes/files.